# Looking for a science fiction/fantasy game from my youth

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember playing this game in my youth, so sometimes in the late 90s or possibly early 2000s.
The game had both Sci-fi and fantasy mixed up together. I think that the main character was called tom or Tommy or possibly Joe. (not quite sure there)

The setting was on a different planet and I remember that there  were some aliens you could recruit in your party.

Cant remember the game or if it had a book attached to it. My kid is about the age I was back then and I would love for him to try this marvel of the last century for himself coz it seems that the saying "apple doesn't fall far from the tree" is true in this case. We like the same games and we both have an uncanny way of finding games we like.

EDIT: As Richard kindly pointed out I forgot something important.
The game was for PC and it was a RPG game.

So the question is what is the name of the game?
and
Does the game have a "world setting" like Dragon lance, Forgotten realm or is it a standalone?

Comment: Do you remember if it was a PC game or was it on a console? Have a look here: https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_msdos?and[]=DOS%20games or https://archive.org/details/classicpcgames

Comment: What kind of game was it? Graphical adventure or side - scroller or what?

Comment: it was a PC game and the genre was RPG.

Comment: Do you remember the graphical style of the game at all?  IE, was it first-person, third-person, isometric, top-down, etc?

Comment: I didn't even realize it was a video game at first - I dimly remember many board games from my youth that I couldn't put a name to today.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's hard know for sure, but it might be [Albion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albion_(video_game)).  I vaguely remember playing the demo of this game back in the 90's (it was released in 1995), but never heard anything about it after that.  The main character's name is Tom, who crash lands on an alien planet and can recruit party members (including aliens) to adventure with.

[image]

Comment: OMG! That is it!! Thank you very much for helping. The game was awesome, story was awesome, gameplay was awesome and it was sooo huge. Unfortunatley when the game got translated into English and came to the marked there was a little addictive think called Red Alert that every single kid on the planet played so Albion didn't get to shine.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad to know that I didn't just hallucinate this game in my youth.

Comment: Very few German game developers out there. Loved this one BTW, and [The Settlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Settlers) by the same company.

Comment: The Settlers was digital heroin for me as a kid.

Comment: Red Alert totally had me hooked at that time too, so your right @Cherubel